# How to format a compact flash disk with ext3 filesystem, when the device is apparently in use by the system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, filesystems

I would like to format a 2 GB compact flash disk in the `ext3` format under Linux (Ubuntu). To do so, I

- put the flsh card into the flash card reader
- checked `dmesg` to see the device is under `/dev/sdb`
- Typed the command `sudo mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb`

which resulted in the following error:

```
mke2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
/dev/sdb is entire device, not just one partition!
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
/dev/sdb is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!
```

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device is used by the system because it is mounted. 
You need to unmount it before doing the **mkfs** command.

Unmount it

```
unmount /dev/sdb
```

Check if mounted

```
df -h
```

Comment: But when did I mount the device? In which step?

Comment: When you plug the device in it's normally mounted automatically by the OS.

Comment: I was sure I disabled that. But maybe not. Thanks, our answer is correct